# Highcharts Stock Chart, Series Padding?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

The line series goes all the way to edge of the plot, is there a way to add some padding?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `minPadding` and `maxPadding` properties:

```
    xAxis: {
        minPadding: 0.5,
        maxPadding: 0.5
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m43trdny/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.maxPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.minPadding

Comment: I am using line series. If you remove type: 'scatter' the min/max padding is not applied. Have not found a solution yet.

Comment: Hi @fotios, In this case you need to also disable the `oridinal` option, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fmn0y4aj/

Comment: Thanks, that works for the margins, but unfortunately it changes the spacing of the ticks a lot.

Comment: Please check API for the `ordinal` proeprty: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal. Unfortunately the padding options don't work with it. Another way is to use `setExtremes` method, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c1byujw4/

Comment: I will use the setExtremes approach. Thanks a lot.